# Functional equation with incommensurable periods

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, irrational-numbers, almost-periodic-functions

Consider the homogeneous functional equations

\begin{equation*}
au(x+s)+bu(x+r)=0,\text{ }x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
.
\end{equation*}

It is known that for $a=1,b=-1$ and $u$ is periodic that $u$ is constant if
and only if $\frac{s}{r}\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
.$
For example, [The sum of two continuous periodic functions is periodic if and only if the ratio of their periods is rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356802/the-sum-of-two-continuous-periodic-functions-is-periodic-if-and-only-if-the-rati/1356844#1356844)
or [A real continuous periodic function with two incommensurate periods is constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775718/a-real-continuous-periodic-function-with-two-incommensurate-periods-is-constant)

My question: What can happens if $a,b$ are arbitrary coefficients with $\frac{s}{r}\notin 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
$.? Can we prove the non-existence of such a function $u$ under a
suitable conditions on $a$ and $b$?.

If we look for a solution of the exponential form $u(x)=Ce^{\lambda x},$
then we find that under a suitable assumption on $a$ and $b$ the solution
exists if and only if $\frac{s}{r}\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
.$ However, we don't know if this form of solution is the unique one.

Is there any reference that treats this case or any ideas?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=b=0$ then $u$ can be anything. Otherwise, without loss of generality let $b \ne 0$ and define

$$v(x) \equiv u(x+s),$$
$$c \equiv -a/b,$$
$$ q \equiv r - s.$$

Then, the original equation becomes

$$v(x+q) = c v(x).$$

Then, we could specify the value of $v(x)$ for $0 \le x < q$ and otherwise obtain the solution

$$v(x) = v(x- nq)c^n,$$

where $n$ is an integer chosen so that $0 \le x - n q < q$. Then, we just undo my redefinitions to obtain $u(x)$.

Comment: thank you sir for the answer; what if the equations is pose on (0,1) instead of the real line?.

Comment: @Gustave thanks. If everything else is the same but $x$ is restricted to $(0,1)$ the answer stays the same except the result only applies on that restricted domain, right? Are you trying to enforce some sort of periodicity, like that $u(x+1)=u(x)$? Based on the analysis already presented, I think the solutions can only be periodic if $b = \pm a$.

Comment: Thank you @David, I want to find a necessary and sufficient conditions on the coefficients for the existence of such solution. I'm not looking for periodicity properties.

Comment: @Gustave well if I'm understanding the setup properly, getting a nontrivial periodicity requires some positive integer power of $b/a$ to be unity. Since $b/a$ is a real number, that means you need $b = \pm a$.

Comment: Thank you @David again. I'm not looking for the existence of periodic solutions. My question is the following: Under what assumption on the coefficients so that the unique solution is the null one ( r/s is irrational).  Do you know any référence which deals with this kind of problems?.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Gustave Per my original answer, I don't think there is a set parameters for which the null solution is the only one. As I said, the answer only seems to depend (nontrivially) on $r,s$ through the difference, $r-s$. I don't see why it would matter at all whether $r/s$ or anything else is rational or irrational.

Comment: Thank you @David for helping me.

Comment: @Gustave No problem, best of luck with your study.